# Controlling exit IP dynamically in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip

I have an invoice generation service that calls a government service for generating these invoices. However, each corresponding entity for which the invoice is being generated has to whitelist a unique IP, which will have to be used to call the govt service when generating an invoice for such an entity. All the IPs for all entities in question have been generated as ElasticIPs under the aws account of my service, so I have full control and knowledge of them both in the account and in the code that actually runs the service.

How then can I pick which exit IP will be used when talking to the govt service?

My service currently uses ECS-Fargate, and it calls the govt service using TLS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this that is generally used is to place your tasks in a **private subnets** and access internet, or your gov API, through [NAT gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html).

The reason is that NAT has Elastic IP. Thus you can wihtlist only this IP in your gov API, and all your task will use the NAT's IP address to query the API.

This solves the problem of worrying and tracking any other public IPs.

Comment: I am required to whitelist a unique IP for each entity, this is not optional.